# Should i hide a widget before destroying it?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

When destroying a widget in GTK3, is it necessary (or good practice) to hide it first?

```
GtkWidget *widgetPointer = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_widget_hide(widgetPointer); /* Is it necessary to call this first? */
gtk_widget_destroy(widgetPointer);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary, and not customary.

That it's not necessary you can find out by just trying it ;-) The explanation behind it is that when a widget is destroyed, it is first removed from its parent container, which effectively hides it first; and widgets generally don't render themselves onto the screen immediately, but wait until your function has finished and control returns to the GTK main loop.

Comment: Some explanation or going into a little more detail would undoubtedly be useful for the OP and many other readers. At this level of detail, the answer would be better as a comment.